# How to use my custom widget in a custom form

Tags: forms

I have developed a custom widget for the paragraph fields. It is working very well.

Now, I would like to add this widget in a render array of a custom form.

What is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a good way... feel free to comment:

1-Create an Element which will display the custom widget

2-Move a maximum of the logic from the widget to the element

3-Use the element in the widget